# Super simple django e-mail based user registration system?

Tags: python, django, registration

I found the django-registration app, but it seems to complex for what I am trying to do. I want users to simply enter their e-mail (username) + a password and automatically be registered. No activations or confirmations. Hacker News style. Does anyone know what the simplest way to implement this would be? Is there something pre-existing out there that you know of (I couldn't find anything), should I somehow modify django-registration, or build this on my own?

Comment: don't use the `django-registration` app.  save username/password, and you're done.  what's the question here?

Comment: create a simple app, with simple form.

Comment: ok, I was just over thinking this. All I need to do then is just save username + pass and store it. got it. thanks

Comment: what logic do I then use when people want to login? I loop through the entire database of usernames and look for a match?

Answer (score 3):

**Login/Authentication**

To make Django authenticate using email/password instead of username/password, you will need to add to your settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('myproject.myauthenticationbackend')
```

This authentication backend needs to be able to authenticate a user based on email/password. A good email authentication backend can be found here: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/74/

**User Registration**

Normally, your registration form will ask user for the email and password. However, Django's auth User model requires every user have a username. One way to handle adding a username is - upon saving of the registration modelForm, generate a random username (since we're not using it anyways).

You will need to check manually that the email the user has entered is already registered in your system.

I've also written a blog post about it a while back and has more complete notes on email authentication. It also includes a sample email/password registration form:

http://www.xairon.net/2011/05/django-email-only-authentication/

Comment: From your blog post, where do I put that code? In the models.py file? What form do I use to allow people to create their own username?

Comment: The community convention is to keep form classes in forms.py (in the same directory as where your views.py is). However there really is no restrictions where you put the class, as long as you import it properly when you use it. Definitely read up: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any app which is doing that but it seems quite simple. I don't think it is necessary to modify and use django-registration in this case.

Create a form that will ask for email and password and then create the corresponding user. The username may be generated from a slug of the email address.

Look at the following snippet for allowing to authenticate with an email address. http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/74/

Comment: which file do I put that code into? Do I need to make a form for people to enter that into?

Comment: The snippet is a auth backend. Put that in a python file (eg email-auth.py) and register it in the settings.py AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('yourproject.email-auth.EmailBackend',) . See snippet description for details